# べんきょうを します / べんきょうします interpretation and use

Tags: grammar

I was told that in

- べんきょうを します

the 
**べんきょう** is the direct object of the expresion and in

- ~を べんきょうします

the **~** part is the direct object
Is that right? but besides that, whats the diference?, how must be interpreted and used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In べんきょうを します, べんきょう is functioning as a noun. So, the literal translation of this phrase is "do studying", and the direct object is べんきょう. If you want to specify what you're studying, you can say ~の　べんきょうを します like "do studying of ~".

On the other hand, in ~を　べんきょうします, べんきょうします is a verb "study". So, the literal translation is "study ~", and the direct object is ~.

I think there is no difference in use between the two phrases. they just mean the same thing.

Comment: then it would be equally accepted as correct in a everyday use?

Comment: Yes, they are both correct.